# Why is there a rectangle in the beginning of some svg's?

Tags: svg

I have noticed that there is a `rect` tag in the beginning of some `svg` files. Like:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 256 256" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect fill="none" height="256" width="256"/>
...
```

I don't know why it's there. But since it didn't do anything, I removed it. And that's where it hit me: Maybe it helps with calculating `svg`'s size in different browsers! So, I searched a little bit and found nothing. Which brought me here.

Comment: No, scaling the SVG is governed by the `viewBox` attribute. Are these SVG files used as recipients of pointer events in a host document (like clicking an an icon)? In that case, the `<rect>`could be configured to ensure the complete area of the SVG can receive the events. But you would need to actively set additional CSS styling to achieve that. Otherwise, it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, two things. Like ccprog points to in the comments there is something about the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). But I think, more importantly, there is also something about the size of the SVG.

Here, first the pointer-event example. If the the pointer-event attribute or CSS property is defined, it is the content of the SVG that is the target when you click on the SVG:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e.target.nodeName);
});
```

```css
svg {
  border: thin solid black;
  margin: .1em;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>No pointer-event defined:</p>
<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 256 256"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect fill="none" height="256" width="256"/>
</svg>
<p>Pointer-event defined:</p>
<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 256 256"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" pointer-events="all">
  <rect fill="none" height="256" width="256"/>
</svg>
```

So the second example points to the size of the SVG. I you ask for the [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) on the SVG the one with the `<rect>` will return the size of the viewBox.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('svg')].forEach(svg => {
  let box1 = svg.getBBox();
  let box2 = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log("Width and height of bbox:", box1.width, box1.height);
});
```

```css
svg {
  border: thin solid black;
  margin: .1em;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 256 256"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="128" cy="128" r="100" fill="orange" />
</svg>
<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 256 256"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect fill="none" height="256" width="256"/>
  <circle cx="128" cy="128" r="100" fill="orange" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Since the coordinate system of the returned values is the local one, you could also read `svg.viewBox.baseVal` and get the same values.

Comment: @ccprog Good point. I guess we can agree that the importance of that `<rect>` is minor.